# Rails import JSON not creating object in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

So I'm importing a JSON file, but when I go and create the object, the id is not being generated.

Here's my import method:

```
namespace :fieldfacts do
  desc "Import Topics"
  task :import_topics => :environment do
    records = JSON.parse(File.read('public/topics.json'))
    records.each do |record|
      a = Topic.create
      a.name = record['name']
      a.save
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the error:

[image]

And I don't think it's being saved without an id. So how do I get an id in there? Thanks!

EDIT: According to the topic model, I need to set a user_id through topics_owners, but how do I do that?

Topic Model

```
  has_many :topics_owners
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :topics_owners
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_ids, presence: {:message => "There must be an assigned Topic Owner to continue."}
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

Controller

```
def topic_params
      params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :active, [keywords: [:id, :keyword]], [keywords_deleted: [:keyword]], :keywords_list, :keywords_list_deleted,
        :organizations_list, :organizations_list_deleted, [organizations: [:id, :organization]], [organizations_deleted: [:organization]],
        :social_groups_list, :social_groups_list_deleted, [social_groups: [:id, :social_group]], [social_groups_deleted: [:social_group]],
        :feeds_list, :feeds_list_deleted, [feeds: [:id, :feed, :source_url]], [feeds_deleted: [:feed]],
        {:articles_list => []}, :articles_list_deleted, :influencers, {:feeds_list => []},
        :articles_object, {:feeds_object => []}, :topic_api_id, :read_only, {user_ids: []}, {:influencers_ids => []},
        [:people_relevants => [:name, :id, :influencer_id, :topic_id]],
        [influencers_adds: [:id, :weight, :influencers_add]], [:influencers_deleted => [:id]], [:influencers_list_deleted => [:id => []]],
        [people: [:id, :person, :weight]], [people_deleted: [:person]],
        [influencers_topics_attributes: [:influencer_id, :id, :_destroy]], :updater_id, :creator_id,
        [influencer_attributes: [:name, :active]])
    end
```

Schema.rb

```
  create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "influencers_topics_count", default: 0,     null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "creator_id"
    t.integer  "updater_id"
    t.boolean  "read_only"
    t.string   "topic_api_id"
    t.integer  "people_relevants_count"
    t.boolean  "active",                   default: false
    t.datetime "activation_date"
  end

  add_index "topics", ["name"], name: "index_topics_on_name", using: :btree

  create_table "topics_owners", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "topic_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "topics_owners", ["topic_id"], name: "index_topics_owners_on_topic_id", using: :btree
  add_index "topics_owners", ["user_id"], name: "index_topics_owners_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: Do you have any validations on `Topic` model?

Comment: This is in the Topic model.

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_ids, presence: {:message => "There must be an assigned Topic Owner to continue."}
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

Comment: The validations are the problems for you. Fire up `rails console` and try the commands. You'll see exactly what's going on. Try using `a = Topic.new` instead of `a = Topic.create` and build up `a` before you save it.

Comment: Cool, I've give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Or if you can pass the attributes during create that might save you a few lines of code, e.g. `Topic.create(name: '...', user_ids: '...')`

Comment: I edited the post with the schema. It's not letting me do 'a.user_ids=1'. How do I pass a user_id(s) in there?

Comment: What exactly is `user_ids`, don't see that in your database table? I assumed `user_ids` was a column in your `topic` table earlier!

Comment: has_many :topics_owners
  has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :topics_owners

Comment: Apparently it's an association.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `a.save!` instead of `a.save` (and the same with `create`). The non-bang returns `true` or `false` for success/failure (which you are ignoring). The bang version raises an exception on failure. That will let you know immediately that something is wrong.

Also if you want to find out what the problem is, you can check `a.errors`, especially `a.errors.full_messages` (with the non-bang `save` and `create` so you still have a reference to `a`). In this case the problem is some of your validations are failing (`user_ids` is required, maybe also a non-unique `name`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The errors told me I need -- validates :user_ids, presence: {:message => "There must be an assigned Topic Owner to continue."}.  Any chance you could tell me how to do that in my rake task?